# fast way to compare whether the number is in the list of ranges in python

Tags: python, list, data-structures, compare, range

I need to compare a list of number to a list of range and see is the number is inside any of range.

Example:

```
list1 = [23,100,1,50,60,73]
list2 = [[0-10],[25-35],[100-110],[75-85]]
```

So i need to iterate list1 and compare this number with the list of range and see if this number fall in any of the range, if yes, i will increase the counter for that range.

both lists will be very big (100k to few millions or more) and the number is random.

So what is the best way to handle this problem?

Edit - the format of list could be list like [low,high,counter]. The example above is data sample and it is not really follow Python code syntax. both list will be huge.

Also the number is int.

Thanks.

Comment: ranges are non-overlapping?

Comment: What is the format of list2? Is it list of lists or list of strings?

Comment: _"both lists will be very big (100k to a few million or more)"_ are you saying you are looking at 100,000 different _ranges_ or 100,000 numbers that you have to fit in these range buckets?

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: So the expected result could be - [0-10], 3 where 3 is the count of item that fall within the range [0-10]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way is to have the second list in form of tuples (or two-element lists) and then use `any`:

```
list1 = [23,100,1,50,60,73]
list2 = [(0,10), (25,35), (100,110), (75,85)]

[any(y[0] <= x <= y[1] for y in list2) for x in list1]
```

timeit gives:

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.17 us per loop
```

---

Now, I assume your ranges are inclusive, that is such numbers as 85 and 25 are inside. If numbers in `list1` are integers, and `list2` is static (and also contains only ints, plus the ranges are *non-overlapping*), flatten it out, sort it and shift borders by 0.5 to get rid of border-cases, then you can use very efficient `bisect` O(log(N)) algorithm:

```
list2 = [(0,10),(25,35),(100,110),(75,85)]
list2 = [x for tup in list2 for x in tup]
list2.sort()
list2 = [l - 0.5 + i%2 for i,l in enumerate(list2)]
timeit [bisect_left(list2, x)%2 == 1 for x in list1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.64 us per loop
```

This is a less readable design because you have a bunch of numbers with no obvious indication where is left border where is right, but it is considerably quicker and more scalable. Here if the number from `list1` gets into a place with even index, it is in between the ranges, otherwise, it is inside.

---

It is still slower than simply storing all the numbers in set and using `in` (which will only work if your numbers in `list1` are all `int`s):

```
list3 = set(range(0,11) + range(25,36) + range(100,111) + range(75,86))
[x in list3 for x in list1]
```

which gives:

```
1000000 loops, best of 3: 376 ns per loop
```

This solution could be not viable for you because if your second list is indeed huge, it will likely not even fit in memory.

Comment: I think that aborting the search only works if the ranges are *sorted*.  And, if they're sorted, there might be some speedups to be found in the `bisect` module... (Your `O(N)` inner loop becomes an `O(logN)` inner loop).

Comment: @mgilson Yes, I'm thinking `bisect` could help. Since I assume that list2 is static, we can manipulate it once and leave it sorted...

Comment: How about using `set` instead of `list` for the second approach? `list3 = set(range(0,11) + range(25,36) + range(100,111) + range(75,86))`

Comment: @falsetru -- But what if the numbers in `list1` end up being floats ;-)  I think we need more constraints from OP on this one...

Comment: @falsetru Why would it be any better than just `range`?

Comment: @sashkello -- the `in` lookup is *usually* O(1) rather than O(N)

Comment: @mgilson, Yeah, I assumed there are only `int`s. I just wanted to let sashkello know there's another option.

Comment: Sorry, guys, I made a mistake in my `range` test and it is actually pretty quick! (edited)

Comment: @sashkello -- can i use the set method is range is overlapped?

Comment: @chengwee Yes, you can.

Comment: @sashkello - Thanks for your answer. I think i will try the bisect method.